# python extract variable from a list

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm pretty new to python and I'm stacked on a simple problem:
i have a list:

`mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

if I extract one element like this:

`print(my_list[1:2])`

I get a list of one element, but i cannot compute any calculus by treating it as a variable :

`print(my_list[1:2]+1)`

because i get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\...\test_tuple.py", line XX, in <module>
> print(my_list[1:2]+1)
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

how do I convert this single element list to a variable?

Comment: Try `my_list[1]`.

Comment: since you are doing slicing you are getting another list as a result, if you want to obtain the first variable from that list, you need to do something like this, `print(my_list[1:2][0]+1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing, with `:`, is slicing. This means grabbing a piece of a list as a new list. What you want is just one index, which you can do be using:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(mylist[2]+1)
```

You can also turn a one element list into a variable by using:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_list = mylist[1:2]
print(new_list[0]+1)
```

Lastly you can also use numpy arrays on which you can perform calculations as if it were a normal number as follows:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_arr = np.array(mylist[1:2])
print(new_arr+1)
```

of course the first solution is the best in this case, but sometimes other solutions can fit your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You're error is about, you are adding number to `[]`,

you need to add number to number like below code;

```
print(my_list[1:2+1])

print(my_list[2+1])

print(my_list[2]+1) ##here youre adding to the value like (my_list[2])3+1 that it will not give you error
```